# Threads with Classes and std::packaged_task

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, threadpool

I'm trying to implement this Thread Pool with classes in C++.
Since now I was confident to have understand how classes work but now I'm getting mad.

I have 2 files 
"JobScheduler.h" and "JobScheduler.cpp"

JobScheduler.h

```
class JobScheduler {
    int thread_id;
    std::vector<std::thread> pool;
    std::mutex m1;

    int set_id();
public:
    JobScheduler();
    ~JobScheduler();

    void Start();
};
```

JobScheduler.cpp

```
int id = 0;
std::mutex m;

JobScheduler::JobScheduler() {...}

JobScheduler::~JobScheduler() {...}

int JobScheduler::set_id() {
    m1.lock();
    int tmp_id = thread_id;
    thread_id++;
    std::cout << "id = " << tmp_id << "\n";
    m1.unlock();
    return tmp_id;;
}

int set_id_02(){
    m.lock();
    int tmp_id = id;
    id++;
    std::cout << "id = " << tmp_id << "\n";
    m.unlock();
    return tmp_id;
}

void JobScheduler::Start(){
    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    /*
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++){
        pool.emplace_back(std::thread(std::packaged_task<void()>(JobScheduler::set_id))); // <--- error 
    }

    ... // print something and join threads
    */

    // MANY THREADS - NO CLASS METHOD AS FUNCTION AND GLOBAL CPP VARIABLE - WORK
    /*
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++){
        pool.emplace_back(std::thread(std::packaged_task<int()>(set_id_02)));
    }

    ... // print something and join threads
    */
}
```

now if I use a function defined in .cpp it works fine but if I try to use a function I defined in the class it doesn't work but I need to be able to access Class variables.

So I have a lot of doubts:
1) why this doesn't work, what am I getting wrong?
2) it's ok to create a std::package_task like I do in the for? Or should I do something like

```
std::pakaged_task<int()> main_task(set_id);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++){
    pool.emplace_back(std::thread(main_task));
}
```

3) in both cases how can I access the future of the task I created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It's not working because you are creating the packaged task wrongly.

Since you are trying to use a member function you have to specify which object is going to be used to call those functions so you can try different approaches

- Bind the object with the member function
- Use a lambda as a proxy

  ```
  std::packaged_task<int()>(std::bind(&JobScheduler::set_id, this))
  std::packaged_task<int()>([this]{ return set_id(); })
  ```

For the second function is enough to just pass the function since it's a "free" function

```
std::packaged_task<int()>(set_id_02);
```

2) See above

3) In order to access the results of your packaged_task you must store its future

```
std::vector<std::future<int>> results;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++){
  auto task = std::packaged_task<int()>([this]{ return set_id(); });
  results.emplace_back(task.get_future());
  pool.emplace_back(std::thread(std::move(task)));
}

//Access results

for (auto& f : results) {
  cout << f.get() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly say, the problem is that you have to provide the object on which you want to call the member function. I see two solutions for that

```cpp
// 1st wrap in a lambda
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++){
    pool.emplace_back(std::thread(std::packaged_task<void()>([this](){this->set_id();}))); 
}

// 2nd Use std::mem_fn and std::bind
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++){
    pool.emplace_back(std::thread(std::packaged_task<void()>(std::bind(std::mem_fn(&JobScheduler::set_id), *this)))); 
}
```

The first one should be clear, I think. In the second, `std::mem_fn` creates a function `f` such that `f(object)` does `object.set_id()` and `std::bind` creates a function `g` such that `g()` does `f(this)`.

I prefer the first solution. It is one of many cases where lambdas are much simpler than using `bind`.